# How do I resize an image in Swift in response to an IBAction?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, ibaction

I have the Swift code below in Xcode, and I am trying to program the sizeSelected function to make the dimensions of my pizzaIcon.png image become slightly bigger (90 by 90 pixels) when the value is changed on a `UISegmentedControl` object. The pizzaIcon.png image is connected to the `viewController` with an `IBAction` called `sizeSelected()`.

I read every stack overflow on this and I couldn't get any of the suggestions to work.

What function/method will work if I paste it to the bottom of my code, and how exactly do I call the image resizing function from the `sizeSelected()` function below?

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

var crustSelected = "NY-Style"
var orderType = "Takeout"
let pickerViewArray = ["NY-Style","Stuffed","Chicago-Style","Neapolitan"];
var sauceChoice = "whole"
var pizzaSize = "small"
var order1Text = Bool()
var order2Text = Bool()



func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerViewArray[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerViewArray.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    crustSelected = pickerViewArray[row]
}


@IBOutlet weak var orderTypeToggle: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var myPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var sauceChoiceToggle: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var sizeChoiceControl: UISegmentedControl!

    //I created this image outlet by connecting the image to the viewcontroller
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func indexChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch sauceChoiceToggle.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        sauceChoice = "the whole";
    case 1:
        sauceChoice = "the left-side of the";
    case 2:
        sauceChoice = "the right-side of the";
    case 3:
        sauceChoice = "none of the";
    default: 
        break; 
    }

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var DestViewController : ThirdViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ThirdViewController



    if (DestViewController.order1Text == "" ) {
    DestViewController.order1Text = "\(pizzaSize) \(crustSelected) crust pizza, sauce on \(sauceChoice) pizza"
    } else {
    DestViewController.order2Text = "\(pizzaSize) \(crustSelected) crust pizza, sauce on \(sauceChoice) pizza"
    }



}


@IBAction func sizeSelected() {

    //I want to call the image resizing method here

}


@IBAction func SubmitOrderClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    orderType = orderTypeToggle.titleForSegmentAtIndex(orderTypeToggle.selectedSegmentIndex)!

    pizzaSize = sizeChoiceControl.titleForSegmentAtIndex(sizeChoiceControl.selectedSegmentIndex)!

    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "Order Submitted"
    alertView.message = "You have successfully submitted a \(orderType) order for a \(pizzaSize) \(crustSelected) crust pizza, with sauce placed on \(sauceChoice) pizza."
    alertView.delegate = self
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertView.show()

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Where is the image you want to resize? Do you just need the size changed on-screen? Or do you want to actually modify the bits? Where do you want to call `sizeSelected()` from?

Comment: Yes I just need the size of the image changed on-screen. It is called "pizzaIcon.png". The sizeSelected() is an IBAction that is triggered when items are selected on a segment control object that I placed on the user interface. I want to place code within sizeSelected() that will make my image a little bit bigger. Currently it is 85 x 85. I want the code to make it be 100 x 100.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I'm guessing `pizzaIcon.png` is already set as the `.image` in `@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!`

Several ways to "resize" it, depending on if you are using constraints or not, but foe example:

```
// if NOT using constraints

let rct = myImageVIew.frame

if rct.width == 85 {

    myImageVIew.frame = rct.insetBy(dx: 15, dy: 15)

} else {

    myImageVIew.frame = rct.insetBy(dx: -15, dy: -15)

}
```

or

```
// assuming myImageView has a 1:1 ratio constraint, and
// connected to myImageView's height constraint

@IBOutlet weak var myImageViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

// if YES using constraints

if myImageViewHeightConstraint.constant == 85 {

    myImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100

} else {

    myImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 85

}
```

Since you are only switching between 85x85 and 100x100, you would probably be fine with `pizzaIcon.png` having a native size of 100x100 / 200x200 / 300x300, and letting UIImageView handle the scaling with Scale to Fill. If that doesn't look good enough, then you'll also want to swap the `.image` to the appropriate sized `pizzaIcon.png` at the same time you resize the frame.